How to Evaluate the Stability of Localization in Real-Time for Autonomous Mobile Robots?
I'm currently working on an autonomous mobile robot (AMR) project, and I need to ensure that the robot's localization is stable in real-time. Specifically, I'm looking for reliable methods to evaluate the stability of the robot's position estimation to stop the robot if the localization becomes unstable.
Here are some details about my setup:

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Distribution: ROS2 Humble
3D LiDAR: Livox Mid-360
Mapping: Using LIO-SAM for mapping
Localization: Using lidar_localization_ros2 for position estimation

Could you please share some common approaches or best practices for real-time evaluation of localization stability? I'm interested in understanding the following aspects:

Metrics: What metrics are typically used to assess the stability of localization (e.g., position variance, sensor data consistency, estimation error)?
Algorithms: Are there specific algorithms or frameworks that are well-suited for monitoring localization stability in real-time?
Thresholds: How are thresholds for stability determined and applied in practice?

Any insights, references, or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
